# Can a CSharp SOAP request target a Mac OS Server application?

Tags: c#, windows, macos, soap, server

would like to know if a SOAP call made in CSharp on a Windows Server could target an application on a MacOS server (designed for receiving SOAP calls). Is there any issues to foresee ? I have the feeling that it should work but your opinions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see any reason why it *wouldn't* work? I mean, that's the whole point of standardized transmission schemes, isn't it?

Comment: SOAP is a protocol specification, it is platform agnostic.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. That was my feeling indeed but I didn't want to take it for granted and a second opinion was welcome ;)